# Implementing Push notifications for iOS (Server Side)

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We want to be able to push simple text messages to ALL our iphone users. For that we obviously need to create a server side code that stores the device tokens and pushes the messages whenever necessary. Is there any good example on doing this? (Talking about the server code)

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have a look at [easyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) if you want to host it yourself, or visit [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) if you are ok with a hosting service (they have an extensive set of documentation)

Another good site for info is Ray Wenderlich's site which hosts a 2 part tutorial:

- [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)
- [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial: Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2)

Answer (score 14):

```
  // Push Notification code for IPHONE in PHP 
  $deviceToken = $users_rows['gcm_regid'];
    $passphrase = 'pass1234';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'DrinksterDevelopment.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 120, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

    $body['aps'] = array(
       // 'alert' => $_GET["message"].'#'.$_GET["type"].'#'.$_GET["deal_id"],
       'alert' => $_GET["message"],
        'sound' => 'default'
        );
    $body['other'] = $_GET["type"].'#'.$_GET["deal_id"];

    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result_iphone = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result_iphone)
        $msg_iphone = 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;

    else
        $msg_iphone = 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

     mail('jackbrown00001@gmail.com', 'IOSPushMsgStatus', $msg_iphone);
     fclose($fp);
    } //if($users_rows['Platform'] == 'Web' OR $users_rows['Platform'] == 'Android')
```

Comment: If I use a shared hosting server, is it possible for me to upload the cert to it and use this php code? I have tried but couldn't find a way - I use iPage by the way.

Comment: Be aware that Apple treats repeated opening and closing of the APN connection as a denial-of-service attach. If you send push notifications once a day, then opening/closing the connection is Ok according to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using an external service for that such as Urban Airship or [PushApps](http://www.pushapps.mobi).
I more familiar with the last, and I can tell you that besides of "regular" push notifications messages, you also get messaging by segmentation, location or even scheduling notification. It may not seem like a critical features for you at first, but as your user base grow, you'll see how important those features are.